# How to display Google map Side by Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i really need your guys help, please visit my website and scrool to the bottom at the map sector, my map cant align to side by side. Please help what code is needed to add in to align it to side by side.
http://stages.a-wan.com/hybridmotors

Comment: Can you post the code you're using rather than linking to the website?

Comment: <div class="clearfix col-sm-6"></div><div id="gmap" style="height: 440px;"></div>
<div class="clearfix col-sm-6"></div><div id="gmap2" style="height: 440px;"></div>

Comment: but where is The maps? return them back, but they OK now, side by side

Answer (score 0):

It seems your gmaps are outide of the container that you (probably) meant to have them in

```
<div class="clearfix col-sm-6"></div><div id="gmap" style="height: 440px;"></div>
<div class="clearfix col-sm-6"></div><div id="gmap2" style="height: 440px;"></div>
```

Change it to

```
<div class="col-sm-6"><div id="gmap" style="height: 440px;"></div></div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><div id="gmap2" style="height: 440px;"></div></div>
```

And the clearfix should be removed as well, if you want them side-by-side

Comment: Hi sir, i changed as per your request. The map went disappear

Comment: Hello Sean, is the problem fixed now? It seems to be when I look at your site