# How to set Google maps infoWindow on default without pressing it

Tags: javascript

http://stages.a-wan.com/hybridmotors/
Hi guys. can you have a look at my website right at the bottom of my map. When i click in the red marker it will display the infoWindow, but i want it to stay there by default without pressing it. What code should i add? Can you please guide me along from my code what to add in as i'm abit noob here. Thank you

```
var map;

map = new GMaps({
    el: '#gmap2',
    lat: 1.289701,
    lng: 103.812879,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 18,
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    clickable: true
});

var image = '';
map.addMarker({
    lat: 1.289701,
    lng: 103.812879,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    horizontalAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#d3cfcf',
    title: 'Lima',
    infoWindow: {content: '<p>Address: No. 2 Kung Chong Road Singapore 159140</p>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i edited the answer several times :
try :

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:  '<p>Address: No. 2 Kung Chong Road Singapore 159140</p>'
});

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        lat: 1.289701,
        lng: 103.812879,
        icon: image,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#d3cfcf',
        title: 'Lima',
        infoWindow: infoWindow

        }
    });
    var image = '';

    map.addMarker(marker);

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

OR using your code:

```
    var image = '';
    map.addMarker({
        lat: 1.289701,
        lng: 103.812879,
        icon: image,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#d3cfcf',
        title: 'Lima',
        infoWindow: {content: '<p>Address: No. 2 Kung Chong Road Singapore 159140</p>'
        }
    });

    var MarkerIndex = 0;
(map.markers[MarkerIndex].infoWindow).open(map.map,map.markers[MarkerIndex]);
```

Comment: Volkinc thank you i love you so much!!!:). Btw i have one more issue here if you can help me out:( Please take a look at my another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094436/how-to-display-google-map-side-by-side

Comment: hi volkinc i just marked the answer, it is possible to help me with with my another question please?